# Unable to show count from Client Web form

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to display the number of times a method is called from my client windows form application. Below are how the service and client are defined.

In my log file I see the count is incremented per method call but I am not able to see the total count that I put in  the list from my client form.

```
IOperator
{

    SendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage);

    [OperationContract] 
    List<int> GetCount();
}
  [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://X.org/MessageService/"]  
  Operator: IOperator
  {

    private  List<Int32> TotalCount = new List<Int32>();

   public static List<int> TotalCount
    {
        get { return _totalCount; }
        set { _totalCount = value; }
    }
SendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage) 
    {
    if (strMsgId == "02")
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                ++_count;
                TotalCount.Add(_count);
            }
            string debugFileName = "C:\\Test.txt";
            // Write to the file:
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Inbound Message:", strMessage.Substring(549, 27));
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "count:", _count);
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}", "Total Count:", TotalCount.Count);

            result = 0;
        }
    }

    public List<int> GetCount()
    {
        return TotalCount;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to save that total count in some session per a given time and get that count in my text box.I want the total count regardless of the number of clients. TotalCount is static,  defined as private static List _totalCount = new List(); with getter TotalCount.

I didn't explicitly defined the InstanceContextMode for the service and yes the totalcount is showing 0.

Client:

```
 var clientA = new SendServiceReference.SendService();
  Operator clientB = new Operator();

 while ((DateTime.Now - startTime) <= timeoutSpan)
        {

                // Send request to external service and all the requests will be logged to my service since I don't have control over the external service.
              sendMessageResult = clientA.SendMessageToExternalService("01", txtRequest.Text);

        }
  //display the total request received from client A for the give time span
responseCount.Text = clientB.GetCount().Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what binding you are using or if you've explicitly defined the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the service, but from the behavior you've described it sounds like it's the default `PerSession`, which creates a new instance of the service for each client.

What is most likely happening is that you are creating one client to send the messages, which is why you are seeing the counter incremented.  You then create a second client (`client2 = new Operator();`, which creates *another* instance of the service, which means `TotalCount` is either 0 or null (since you don't indicate that you get an error, I'm going to guess that the count `TotalCount` is 0).  In other words, you're no longer accessing/using the instance of the service that incremented the count, but an entirely new instance of the service with its own `TotalCount` field/property.

There are a few ways to resolve this, depending on what your requirements/needs are.

If you need the total count regardless of the number of clients, you can either make `TotalCount` static, or you can set the `InstanceContextMode` to `Single`.  I would discourage using `InstanceContextMode.Single` as that can lead to scaling problems, and go with a static `TotalCount`.

If you need the total count by each client, then you will need to use the same client that made the 10 calls in the loop to make the call to `GetCount()`.  For example:

```
Operator client1 = new Operator();

for (int i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Send your messages
}

responseCount.Text = client1.GetCount().Count.ToString();
```

There's an article on CodeProject that has illustrations of the 3 different `InstanceContextModes` that may be of use for you: [Three ways to do WCF instance management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per)

Comment: I am trying to save that total count in some session per a given time and get that count in my text box.client A is making call to some external service and all the requests will be logged to my service. I want to count how many requests came to my service and save that total count and display it by any means.

Comment: If you want to contain the count only for a certain period of time, then you can set a timer and use the same client during that timer.  Either that or make the total field static, and then reset it (via another service call).